# Flickering when using keyframes + background position on sprite sheet in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, keyframe, background-position

So I have a sprite sheet containing 16 frames of a walking animation and I intent to animate it with keyframes by changing the background position using:

```
animation: abc 0.55s infinite steps(1);


    @keyframes abc {
        0%  {background-position(-2250vh,-10vh);}
        6.67%   {background-position(-2100vh,-10vh);}
        13.33%  {background-position(-1950vh,-10vh);}
        ...
        100%    {background-position(0,-10vh);}
    }
```

It works fine in chrome and firefox but in IE, at the end of the animation, it disappears briefly before looping again. Creating a flickering effect

When I turned the animations off and manually test each position using the console, each frame is displayed correctly, so this is not due to incorrect positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't animate background-position. This does cause performance issues. Instead, use `img` and let it be as tall as it needs. Wrap it in a `div` like so...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src='some-tall-image.png'/>
</div>
```

Adjust the wrapper height to be as tall as a desired frame (From your keyframes i asumed it to be 150px). And **set `overflow:hidden`** on .wrapper

```
.wrapper {
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

This should display only what you want to see. A single frame of your sprite-sheet. And **to animate use `transform:translateY()`** on the `img`

```
@keyframes abc {
    0%  {transform:translateY(-2250vh);}
    6.67%   {transform:translateY(-2100vh);}
    13.33%  {transform:translateY(-1950vh);}
    100%    {transform:translateY(0vh);}
}

.image {
  animation: abc ...;
}
```

## EXAMPLE. Check it out...

BY using `steps(8)` I need only set the 100% keyframe of the animation. The rest gets filled in... MAGIC!... [Also created a JSFiddle for ya](https://jsfiddle.net/jairodev/4Lkb80hL/)

I borrowed the sprite sheet. Props to the creator (whose url can be seen on the code). Image is 960px wide. So in my case I used `translateX` instead of `translateY`.

```css
@keyframes walking {
  100% { 
    transform:translateX(-960px);
   }
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:120px;
}

.image {
  animation:walking 500ms steps(8) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class= "image" src="https://www.adamkhoury.com/demo/sprite_sheets/adam.png">
</div>
```

Comment: 2021: sprite sheet file is missing